# Noise from eletric motor with belt on

Tags: motor

My mini lathe motor has a sort of clicking sound when there's pressure on the shaft from the side.

[Link to 35 second movie with sound.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/VKBMjcEn3Jn4Kojz7)

Is this normal? Does something needs to be replaced? Thank you!

Comment: You might want to ask this on engineering stack exchange. Can you feel anything in the bearing? It doesn't really sound like a bearing to me.

Comment: On SE sites you should upload the photo into your question so we don't have to follow links and so that your question makes sense when the link dies.

Comment: @Transistor it is a video and it is about the sound

Comment: The link contains the word 'photos'. I wouldn't expect to hear anything there. Use the markdown syntax `[link-to-display](url)` to provide a descriptive hyperlink or just explain, "You can hear it here." (Many of us won't follow links just to understand a question.)

Comment: Did the problem start the first time you ran the lathe after purchase? If not, how long have you been using it? If you can adjust the motor speed, how does that affect the noise? It will probably be very difficult to get help based on a description of the noise, but anything you can add to the circumstances associated with the problem might help.

Comment: Does the motor have any built-in speed reduction gear? The speed of the pulley seems quite slow for direct connection to the motor. Is the motor running at the slowest speed setting?

Comment: the click appears to occur at the frequency of 3 clicks per revolution ... it sounds like a cracked gear

Comment: Thank you, kind folks, it was a bad rear bearing AFAIKT. Took a look at the video of the lathe first use, it was there from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only noticeable with axial (along the shaft) pressure, I would suspect a thrust bearing. A thrust bearing is what keeps the motor from moving forward and backward along its axis. These are often ball bearings, so a cracked ball or a broken retaining ring can cause noise like this. If the sheave in your video is not directly attached to the motor shaft, then it could also be something in the coupling.

Comment: Did you mean to say that a "thrust bearing is what keeps the rotor from moving" or a "thrust bearing is what keeps the motor from moving".  Because I think the motor mount keeps the motor from moving. And the thrust bearing insures that the shaft and rotor do not move with respect to the housing.

Comment: JRaef, there are no thrust bearings in this motor, just 2 standard ones which are held from the sides with the motor housing. There wasn't any sound when I tried to spin the bearings but the rear bearing had small vibrations when I hold the shaft by the bearings in hand and spun it. Ordered it, will replace. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a fault in the internal plastic fan blade, either it is damaged or the clearance is insufficient and it is rubbing when the shaft is pushed back.

I would extract the motor and have a look at it, removing the end bells.